# Function is not giving desired result

Tags: php

I am having a php function:

```
<?php
function find_senior($mylevel, $sender){
    global $class_database;
    global $g_level1;
    global $g_level2;
    global $g_level3;

$sponsor=$class_database->getdata("sponsorid", "id='$sender' AND gift_level > '$mylevel'", "user");
$sponsor2=$class_database->getdata("sponsorid", "id='$sender'", "user");
    if(strlen($sponsor) > '0'){
        if($mylevel < $g_level1){
        return array("id"=>"1", "amt"=>$g_level1, "lvl"=>$g_level1);    
        }
        elseif($mylevel < $g_level2){
        return array("id"=>"1", "amt"=>$g_level2, "lvl"=>$g_level2);    
        }
        elseif($mylevel < $g_level3){
        return array("id"=>"1", "amt"=>$g_level3, "lvl"=>$g_level3);    
        }
    }
    elseif(strlen($sponsor) <='0' && strlen($sponsor2) <='0'){
        if($mylevel < $g_level1){
        return array("id"=>"1", "amt"=>$g_level1, "lvl"=>$g_level1);    
        }
        elseif($mylevel < $g_level2){
        return array("id"=>"1", "amt"=>$g_level2, "lvl"=>$g_level2);    
        }
        elseif($mylevel < $g_level3){
        return array("id"=>"1", "amt"=>$g_level3, "lvl"=>$g_level3);    
        }   
    }
elseif(strlen($sponsor) <='0' && strlen($sponsor2) >'0'){
    find_senior($mylevel, $sponsor2);
    }

}

?>
```

it should return as array when we do var_dump()

```
$array=show("100", "2");
var_dump($array);
```

But it is returning only :

```
NULL
```

Where is the error may be ?
I am very new to php, please try to solve this puzzle, I tried a lot, but may be for my limited knowledge I am ubnable to solve it

Comment: Are you defining that function in a class?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://eval.in/129789

Comment: Sidenote: You may want to change `<='0'` to `<=0` etc., since it may be evaluated as a string instead of an integer.

Comment: If you're calling find_senior() recursively, `elseif(strlen($sponsor) <='0' && strlen($sponsor2) >'0'){
    return find_senior($mylevel, $sponsor2);
    }

`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
class myClass{
function show($g_level1, $id){
return array("id"=>$id, "amt"=>$g_level1, "lvl"=>$g_level1);
}
}
```

Now create instance of that class:

```
$instance = new myClass();
$instance->show("100", "2");
```

Comment: Any particular reason why it should be in a class? Or why it should work only if defined in a class and not simply as a function?

Comment: No technical reason. Just for code management. Class will be in different file. Then just include that file in your real page.